Trying to reproduce the button from Ubuntu's file explorer with CSS
I was trying to reproduce those buttons in CSS :

This is what I managed to come up with so far :


.folder-button{
    background-color: #565656;
    color: transparent;
    text-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
       -moz-background-clip: text;
            background-clip: text;

    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: .8em 1.8em;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: inset -4px -7px 12px 2px #0000001f;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #bfbfbf;
    border-style: solid;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    top: 2em;
}
<a href="#" class= "folder-button">Some button</a>



It might be pretty close but I am missing this subtle little highlight at the bottom edge of the text among a few other things. I know it would be caused by an fake text shadow like this but I couldn't find the correct settings to get it right.
If anyone knew how to do it, that'd be great.
Thanks in advance.

it is not a box-shadow. You should try to look into linear-gradient

You mean the highlight in the text or the highlight in the button? Because if it's the button, the highlights are actually present all around the box and not only from one direction and that cannot be done from linear gradient as far as I know.

Could you describe a bit more exactly what shadow you are talking about? Is it that little bit of white below and within each character?

I don't see a highlighting around either inside or outside the buttons. I only see a slighter dark color at the bottom which is linear and as such fit for linear-gradient. But the buttons are so small that it is hard to recognize anything.

@AHaworth Yes. That's what I am talking about.

@tacoshy it is very very subtle, it is visible when you zoom in a bit : https://imgur.com/yd8wDSm

"Is it that little bit of white below and within each character?" - "Yes. That's what I am talking about." => then look into text-shadow

I've done so and couldn't find the correct parameters as I said in the post. There is where I need help.
